# Click on div except the button - Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a simple div with width 100%, with a button in it.

Problem is that when I add a click event to the div, my complete div becomes clickable (including the button as well);

I would want to make the whole div clickable with a different method while the button click with another method.

```
<div class="full-width" @click="method1">
  <button @click="method2">click me</div>
</div>
<script>
export default {
methods: {
  method1() {
    console.log("div is clicked")
  },
  method2() {
    console.log("button is clicked")
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is general bad practice to have click events on cascading items, let alone a div shouldn't be clickable. If you still want to try it though, you would have to check if the item clicked in method1 is different than your button, using `event.target`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two ways to achieve this in vue way:

1. you can use `@click.self` on the `div` and `@click` on the `button`
2. you can use `@click.stop` on the `button` and `@click` on the `div`

the first approach tells the `div` to only listen for the events where the event target is itself and the second one tells the `button` to stop event propagation and therefore click event does not reach the `div`

**edit**: added both approach for the select element

check the demo below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    msg1: '',
    msg2: '',
    msg3: '',
    msg4: '',
  }),
  methods: {
    method1(v) {
      this[v] = 'clicked on div';
    },
    method2(v, elm = 'button') {
      this[v] = `clicked on ${elm}`;
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div style="border: 2px solid red; width: 100%" @click.self="method1('msg1')">
    <button @click="method2('msg1')">click me</button>
  </div>
  <div>{{ msg1 }}</div>

  <div style="border: 2px solid green; width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" @click="method1('msg2')">
    <button @click.stop="method2('msg2')">click me</button>
  </div>
  <div>{{ msg2 }}</div>

  <div style="border: 2px solid blue; width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" @click.self="method1('msg3')">
    <select @click="method2('msg3', 'select')">
      <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
      <option value="dog">Dog</option>
      <option value="cat">Cat</option>
      <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
      <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
      <option value="spider">Spider</option>
      <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: right">{{ msg3 }}</div>

  <div style="border: 2px solid orange; width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" @click="method1('msg4')">
    <select @click.stop="method2('msg4', 'select')">
      <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
      <option value="dog">Dog</option>
      <option value="cat">Cat</option>
      <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
      <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
      <option value="spider">Spider</option>
      <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: right">{{ msg4 }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It fails with select element.

Comment: @power-cut updated the answer and added both approach for the select element

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick.

```html
<template>
  <div id="myDiv" @click="handleDivClick">
    <button id="myButton" @click="handleButtonClick">Click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    handleDivClick(event) {
      if (event.target.id === 'myButton') {
        // The button was clicked
        // Do something here
      } else {
        // The div was clicked, but not the button
        // Do something else here
      }
    },
    handleButtonClick() {
      // The button was clicked
      // Do something here
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

if it doesn't work i suggest you use vanilla javascript to implement this

Comment: it's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer, @Patric .

Comment: My mistake, it should be pretty obvious that the code is almost identical to the one provided by the user (in addition to some comments in the code itself), I’ll try my best to explain things better next time, thank you @DSDMark

Answer (score 0):

Just use @click.stop on the button and @click on the div.
Like this :

```html
<div class="full-width" @click="method1">
  <button @click.stop="method2">click me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about select element ?

Comment: @power-cut , in that case use "@click.self" on the parent : 
```<div class="parent" @click.self="onClickParent"> ... </div>```